# What Effect Does HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\Default Registry Key Have?

Tags: windows, networking, registry

I was looking into making a script which toggles a network adapter's metered or unmetered status. I found [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-windows-10-ethernet-connection-to-metered-with-powershell/) script which allowed me to automatically toggle using registry keys. However, that script was hard coded to toggle an Ethernet connection, I wanted to toggle whichever adapter is primarily in use. I saw that in the registry folder for DefaultMediaCost, which controls metered status, there is a key called Default. I was hoping somebody could tell me what this key affects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need a complicated script for this. Would two .reg files that switch everything to metered, or switches everything back on not do the trick?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost]
"3G"=dword:00000002
"4G"=dword:00000002
"Default"=dword:00000002
"Ethernet"=dword:00000002
"WiFi"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: The issue is that those particularly registry keys require permissions changes in order to allow edits. At least, that is my understanding. If you look at the link I included, the first few steps show the process of giving full control access to Administrators.